# How to turn Android tablet into network photo frame?

Tags: tablet, photos, dlna

I have a qnap NAS which shares media via samba shares and upnp (dlna/twonkey). I'd like to run a photo gallery app which displays shared photos so I don't have to copy them to my tablet. No luck finding a DNA client that has a decent photo gallery yet... also couldn't find an app that lets me mount a smb share like smbfs for Linux.. any other ideas? Launching needs to be very simple.

Comment: Have you considered uploading pictures to your Picasa account and using the dock screen to show them as slideshows?

Comment: +1 Have wondered the same, would be a good way to recycle my tablet when my tablet when it gets past its useful life, as well as a way to get it doing something more useful than pretending to be a clock while its docked and charging. I've got a DLNA enabled Windows server, so any SMB/DLNA solutions would presumably be the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making an Andriod tablet boot into a slideshow - App advice](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16387/making-an-andriod-tablet-boot-into-a-slideshow-app-advice)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Social Frame](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ellevsoft.socialframefree)? 
 
It is a digital photo frame app. 
It automatically syncs photos from Facebook, Twitter, and 500px.
Love this app

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Digital Photo Frame Slide Show](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.wyseur.photo).

It has exactly the features you need as it can access a UPnP server or a SMB network drive.

(I am the developer of Digital Photo Frame Slide Show.)

Comment: \*ahem\* Please see our [FAQ#promotion] on the requirements for recommending products with which you have a vested interest.

Comment: You're right I should have mentioned I develop that app. It does however exactly fit his requirements.

Comment: I'm not disputing that. There's nothing wrong with offering up an app you've developed as a solution (especially if it's an exact fit) _so long as_ you disclose this fact and it's not the only reason you're participating on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you searched `DLNA` in Play Store? You can find many apps.
My favorite is [Skifta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skifta.android.app) .

Answer (score 0):

It may sound like overkill, but it may suit all your needs:

[XBMC Media Center](http://xbmc.org/about) (downloads for Android are [here](http://xbmc.org/download/))

It has many features that you might not need (like a weather forecast, playing videos and music) but the best parts are its big list of [network capabilities](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Configuring_PC_Shares) (media on Windows shares, DLNA (UPnP), FTP, etc.) and its huge list of available plugins. It's also remotely controllable in many ways, there are even apps for Android, etc.

Plus it's open source and free.

Answer (score 0):

Samba Shares and Cloud Image Services (Picasa, Flickr, Facebook, Dropbox and Instagram) [Photo Frame Live Wallpaper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.isanexus.photoframelivewallpaper)

Answer (score 0):

[PhotoCloud Frame Slideshow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.baka.photoframe) should match your requirements since it shows photos on your tablet in a digital frame fashion, downloading them on-the-fly. It supports DLNA/UPNP, but also Samba and a lot of other photo sources.

(Disclaimer: I am the developer of this app)

Answer (score -2):

ES File Explorer should let you access SMB shares.